# ZF3 on nginx only working for parent route

Tags: nginx, zend-framework3

I have two apps. One is simple php file and the other is a zend framework app. I am using Nginx. It is working for simple php app which is accessible via example.com/.

For the ZF3 app, nginx is working only for parent route and none of the child routes are working. The parent route is accessible via example.com/products. I want nginx to handle route actions such as example.com/products/add, example.com/products/view which are already defined in module config.

nginx config

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name           example.com;

  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/simpleapp.access.log combined;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/simpleapp.error.log;

  root /var/www/simpleapp;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }

  location ^~ /products {
    alias /var/www/ecom/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
  }
}
```

nginx log file

`FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream`

What works:

1. example.com/
2. example.com/products

What doesn't work:

1. example.com/products/add
2. example.com/products/view
3. example.com/products/categories

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need two different declarations for very same php processing? I would stick with one and only differentiate the root using alias on `/product` for example:

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name           example.com;

  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/simpleapp.access.log combined;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/simpleapp.error.log;

  root /var/www/simpleapp;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location /products {
      alias /var/www/ecom/public;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```